# I want to store continuous changing value of time in variable and then compare it with other times to do some tasks. how to do it

Tags: java

I want to store continuous changing value of time (in milliseconds) in a variable and then compare it with other time values to do some tasks. How to do it?
Problem is that once my program is compiled, the value of milliseconds stored in variable is same in the whole program and it never changes. All if conditions are compared with same time and the time on which I I want to do some task, never comes. I want comparison of time values with changing time of clock. I shall be very thankful for help.

Here's the code I am using for getting time continuously(I stored it in constructor):

```
    Thread clock = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                millisAt_ONU = cal.getTimeInMillis();

            }

    };

    clock.start();
```

and I use this code to compare it with times (this is future timing - on which my condition will be executed:

```
if(millisAt_ONU == receivedGATE_time8){     
//receivedGATE_time8 is the time which will come

                try {
                    socOnu.sendReportHP(report_ONU_8_HP);
                    socOnu.sendReportLP(report_ONU_8_LP);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("--------------------------------\n");

                System.out.println("Sent REPORT for ONU-8!");

            }
```

Comment: How is `millisAt_ONU` declared? It should probably be `volatile` since you're setting its value within one thread and reading it in another thread.

Comment: Do you realize that chance that `millisAt_ONU == receivedGATE_time8` is `true` is very small?

Comment: `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()` is heavy operation. It is simplier and faster to use `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: I am working on the simulation of a project which is based on optical networks. I have to match milliseconds in order to send and receive data. Please help me in this matter @talex

Comment: Your `clock` thread will be spinning on a CPU which is inefficient and even then, you may not be able to hit that exact millis due to OS scheduling. Please read something about real-time programming before attempting.

Comment: @billc.cn I have no idea how to work with real time programming. Please can you mention if there is any way to compare changing time with some specific time?

Comment: If you can compare it to a range, then maybe. If you want exact millis, it will highly depend on blocking calls in the loop, the OS, the processing power, other processes running on the machine, the state of GC, the temperature in the room, the phase of the moon, the rotation speed of the earth and maybe a million other factors, so no, it cannot work reliably. You'll either have to change this into an interrupt driven program or go for a real-time OS and a real-time-friendly language.

Comment: Do you want to schedule actions to occur at a specific time? For example, what if the test is executed *before* the specified time? Do you mean to wait until `receivedGATE_time8` is reached, and then proceed? Or do you mean, as your code is written, to skip that action forever and move on?

Comment: @billc.cn Should I use manual timer here?

Comment: @erickson I want to wait until receivedGATE_time8 is reached and then proceed

Comment: @Trey millisAt_ONU is declared static in my code

Comment: What do you mean by a "manual timer"? If you can tolerate being waken up a few millis _after_ `receivedGATE_time8`, then `Thread.sleep` is more efficient.

Comment: Manual timer, a loop inside thread and yes with Thread.sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply schedule the tasks to occur at specified times. In this example, `MySystem` is some class that you write to maintain the state of your process. It has methods `someAction1()`, `someAction2()`, … that contain actions like those shown in the question. And `t1`, `t2`, … are the delays, relative to "now" when you want those actions to occur.

```
MySystem system = ... /* Set up whatever you need as a context. */
ScheduledExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
worker.schedule(system::someAction1, t1, TimeUnit.MILLIS);
worker.schedule(system::someAction2, t2, TimeUnit.MILLIS);
...
worker.shutdown();
```

You probably won't get millisecond precision. If you require precise timing, you may need to look into a realtime system.